# Paketo buildpacks - no entrypoint found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, buildpack, paketo

I am trying to build a dotnet application(net6.0) which uses azure functions in the csproj file.
https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-core -> I am trying to build it with these buildpacks , latest version.

The output type is dll(library).
I feel the error is like the runtimeconfig.json generated for .dll file will not have ApplicationName.
But the buildpacks logic has been written in such a way it needs the ApplicationName and thus throwing this error.
The logic -> https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-execute/blob/main/build.go#L100

csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="27.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader" Version="3.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" Version="3.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Devices" Version="1.37.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="Appsettings\appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

## buildpacks participating

1. paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates            3.6.6
2. paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-core-sdk            0.14.2
3. paketo-buildpacks/icu                        0.7.2
4. paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-publish             0.12.24
5. paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-core-aspnet-runtime 0.4.2
6. paketo-buildpacks/dotnet-execute             0.14.25

## command used

/cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=workspace/source/src -layers=/layers -cache-dir=/cache -skip-restore=false -report=/layers/report.toml  -platform=/platform \  -project-metadata=/layers/project-metadata.toml -uid=1001 -gid=1001-stack=/build/stack.toml \ -log-level=info -buildpacks=/build/buildpacks -order=/build/order.toml